# cmd displaying output only after program has finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, timing

I have a problem with my python program, it is supposed to print each character individually with a delay in between.
Here is my code:

```
import time
import os
txt=open("text",'r').read()
delay=0.25
bg,fg=0,2
os.system("color "+str(bg)+str(fg))
for i in txt:
    print(i,end='')
    time.sleep(delay)
```

But when run in cmd it waits until the program is done THEN shows the output.
How can i make this work?

*the "text" file just contains "hello"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flush output of print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function)

Comment: No that does not help me,either of them

Comment: Using `flush=True` does exactly what you asked. Can you please edit your question and point out *exactly* what you want?

Comment: Why not? Have you tried `print(i,end='',flush=True)`?

Comment: what does that do?

Comment: It flushes the output. That's what you're asking for. `print` is buffered output.

Comment: i want it to print one charachter at a time with a delay in between each print

Comment: Have you tried it or not?

Comment: it works. Very well

Comment: It works in Python, regardless what IDE you're using…

Answer (score 1):

`print` is buffered output. It's not immediately printed but stored and printed later. With `flush=True` you can flush the buffer and immediately write the buffer to the terminal.